# Angularjs change url parm and refresh onClick

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm displaying a chart with default values when the page is loaded. I'd like to add angularjs clickable links to change the period (month, week, day) displayed on the chart.

I'm currently doing a regular page reload with `<a href="{{ URL::to('t') }}?c={{ $currency }}&p=1m">1m</a>` but how would it be possible to change the url parm and refreshing the chart without having to reload the page?

html

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="tickerchartsCtrl">
    <canvas class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options"></canvas>

     <a href="{{ URL::to('t') }}?c={{ $currency }}&p=1m">1m</a> --> Change to angularJs onClick instead of page reload
     <a href="{{ URL::to('t') }}?c={{ $currency }}&p=1w">1w</a> --> Change to angularJs onClick instead of page reload
     <a href="{{ URL::to('t') }}?c={{ $currency }}&p=1d">1d</a> --> Change to angularJs onClick instead of page reload

     <input type="hidden" ng-model="currency" name="period" value="{{ $currency }}">
     <input type="hidden" ng-model="period" name="period" value="{{ $period }}">

</div>
</div>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('tickercharts',['chart.js']);
app.controller('tickerchartsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location){

    $scope.currency      = angular.element(document.getElementsByName('currency')).val();
    $scope.period        = angular.element(document.getElementsByName('period')).val();

    var urlapigettickers = $location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + "/api/gettickers?c=" + $scope.currency + "&p=" + $scope.period ;        

    $http.get(urlapigettickers).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.gettickeritems = data.gettickers;

     //console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("No data found..");
  });

}]);
```

Comment: Should you have to update the urls? What if you could refresh that chart without changing the url. If so, I can help

Comment: Well the url is actual my api which need parms to provide different values

Comment: I see you just pass the url to the get request method. If that is what you only do, then there is a better way: use a function.

Comment: Oh ok interesting. Need to change my api or angularjs code? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you just pass the `url` to the get request method. In other words, the url is not used for reloading the page. If so, it is better that you use a `function`

```js
$scope.getData = function(param) {
  $http.get(param).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.gettickeritems = data.gettickers;

    //console.log(data);
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("No data found..");
  });
}

// Call the function with the default argument inside the controller.
$scope.getData("defaultArgument")
```

By default, when you go to the route related to this `controller`, the `getData` function gets called. You must pass the arguments related to the chart that you display by default.

Instead of the `anchor` tags, use buttons and call the function in those three buttons.

```html
<button type="button" ng-click="getData('argument')">1m</button>
<button type="button" ng-click="getData('argument')">1w</button>
<button type="button" ng-click="getData('argument')">1d</button>
```

## Update

Define a new variable for the url inside the function just before the http.get request and concatenate the dynamic parameters with it. In this case, if `param1` and `param2` are static, you should call the function with those two parameters wherever you have used the function.

```js
$scope.getData = function(param1, param2) {
  var url = "www.domain.com/api/gettickers?parm1=" + param1 + "&parm2=" + param2
  $http.get(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.gettickeritems = data.gettickers;

    //console.log(data);
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("No data found..");
  });
}

// Call the function with the default argument inside the controller.
$scope.getData(1, 2)
```

Comment: That's great @mahan, I'm testing this. Should I specify the full path somewhere? I need to be calling `www.domain.com/api/gettickers?parm1=1&parm2=2` but when that function gets called, I only get the `www.domain.com` part

Comment: @user3489502 Updated the answer.