# Get URL parameter elemId and add it to button onClick attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a component (called `histogram`) in AngularJS that displays a chart of data using ChartJS.

It is called by another component (called `cryostat`) using following code:

```
<div id="outer_pressure">Outer pressure ABS:<br/><a href="#!/histogram/PT0104"><span class="value">{{ $ctrl.PT0104[0].Mnish | number: 2 }} bar</span></a><br/>Outer pressure Diff:<br/><a href="#!/histogram/PT0105"><span class="value">{{ $ctrl.PT0105[0].Mnish | number: 2 }} mbar</span></a></div>
```

By default, it's using `elemId` (in this example `PT0104`) to call the data for this element from DB and loads the data for last 3 days.

My URL format is following: `http://server/np04-slow-control/app/#!/histogram/PT0104/3`

What I want to do is to have buttons on `histogram` component page that will allow to load the data in chart for different timespan (last day, last 3 days, last 7 days etc.)

**UPDATE**
Corrected component code according to suggestion

**UPDATE 2**
Rephrased the question to try and make it more clear.

My code of HTML template is following:

```
<style type="text/css">
     #chart-container {
         width: 80%;
         height: 100%;
     }
</style>

<div id="timespan" style="position: relative; left: 5%; top: 10%;">
    <span>History for:</span>

    <a class="btn" id="1day" href="#!/histogram/elemId/1">1 day</a>
    <button id="3days" onclick="#!/histogram/elemId/3">3 days</button>
    <button id="7days" onclick="#!/histogram/elemId/7">7 days</button>
    <button id="all"  onclick="#!/histogram/elemId/10">10 days</button>
</div>
<div id="chart-container">
     <canvas id="hist"></canvas>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('histogram', []).component('histogram', {
    templateUrl: 'histogram/histogram.template.html',
    controller: ['$routeParams', '$http',
        function histogramController($routeParams, $http) {
            this.elemId = $routeParams.elemId;
            if ($routeParams.days != null) {
                console.log(this.days);
                this.days = $routeParams.days;
            } else {
                this.days = 3;
            }
            this.pageTitle = this.elemId;
            this.natalie = 1;
            this.TT0101 = "";
            let self = this;
            let labels = [];
            let values = [];
            $http.get("php-db-conn/histogram.conn.php?elemId=" + this.elemId + "&days=" + this.days).then(function (response) {
            let title = self.elemId;
            let respdata = response.data.records;
            for (let i in self.elemId) {
                    labels.push(moment((respdata[i].TimeStamp), "DD-MMM-YYYY hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS A"));
                    values.push(respdata[i].ExactValue);
                }
                let chartdata = {
                    labels: labels,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: title,
                            tension: 0,
                            pointRadius: 1,
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.001)',
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                            data: values
                        }
                    ]
                };
                let ctx = $('#hist');

                let barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: chartdata,
                    options: {
                        legend: {
                            labels: {
                                fontColor: "white",
                                fontSize: 18
                            }

                        },
                        scales: {
                            xAxes: [{
                                type: "time",
                                time: {
                                    tooltipFormat: "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss",
                                    displayFormats: {
                                        millisecond: "HH:mm:ss.SSS",
                                        second: "HH:mm:ss",
                                        minute: "HH:mm",
                                        hour: "DD/MM HH:mm",
                                        day: "DD/MM/YYYY",
                                        week: "DD/MM",
                                        month: "MM YYYY",
                                        year: "YYYY"
                                    }
                                },
                                ticks: {

                                    fontColor: "white"
                                }
                            }],
                            yAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    fontColor: "white"
                                }

                            }]
                        }
                    }
                });
                console.log(labels);
            });
        }
    ]
});
```

What I want is to get SPAREAI and append it to onclick url. I marked id with elemId in code

Comment: Where is your controller code? See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Satpal, I have added a controller code

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50337512/angularjs-change-url-parm-and-refresh-onclick/50338425#50338425

Comment: @mahan, thank you for your comment. I tried doing that way, but it only loads initial page, and buttons don't react on click anyway

Comment: could you make a codepen of it?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/giosal/1ced1e84ecc9c47f88ee3bf72d145a7a

Comment: https://gist.github.com/giosal/5d1f49c459f4a1052a4221bd06229131

Comment: @mahan, here you go: https://codepen.io/giosal/pen/WJBQbG

Comment: Why do you sand an another request inside the first request? Should you have to use `routeParams` for the first button? Doesn't it update the chart or doesn't get data from server?

Comment: because, by default, when called from another component, it loads data for last 3 days, but I want to have buttons that will load data from last 1 day, 3 days, 7 days etc.

Comment: @mahan, I have rephrased the question to try and make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thorough research I was finally able to make it work.

**Controller**
Added following function to the controller code:
    `this.dayChanger = function(funcdays) {
        $window.location.href = "#!/histogram/" + this.elemId + "/" + funcdays;
    }`

**HTML template**
Changed the buttons to following:

`<button id="3days" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.dayChanger(3)">3 days</button>`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you reusing the elemId varible in our code in your code:

Here you get the elemId from routeParams

```
    this.elemId = $routeParams.elemId;
```

Here you assign "this" to self and reassign elemId:

```
    let self = this;

   let labels = [];
        let values = [];
        $http.get().then(function (response) {

        let title = self.elemId;
        self.elemId = response.data.records;   **<---- This is the problem**
```

Now when you try to access elemIdin template it does not point to "$routeParams.elemId" instead it points to response.data.records. in JS "=" operator does not deep copy objects. In your case "self" and "this" both points to same object reference.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This does help, but still doesn't give me the answer to the question - how can I change put elemId in onclick attribute of a button?

Comment: You mean something like this? ng-click="onButtonClick(elemId)"? or can I see your button onClick handler?

Comment: yes, exactly something like this.
You can see updated code in gists in comments to my question or in my HTML code there is the idea what I want

Comment: Define a function in your controller and do something like this in HTML: